# Return z values of 3D scipy.spatial.Delaunay

Tags: python, scipy, delaunay

I have the following code which creates the surface:

```
u = np.array(mat) 
v = np.array(stk) 

x = u
y = v
z = np.array(vol)

tri = Delaunay(np.array([u,v]).T)
```

[image]

I'd like to compare the surface with my full data set and find the RMSE. However, to do so I need to find the z values of points on the surface which are not the vertices of simplices. How should I go about doing so?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scipy.interpolate.LinearNDInterpolator`.

Example usage:

```
interpolator = LinearNDInterpolator(tri, z)
interpolator(200, 200)
```

or with an array of points:

```
interpolator(np.array([x,y]).T)
```